# Unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying  to install Indigo-desktop-full on Ubuntu 14.04.  I am going through the install for Indigo.  I have set up my keys, and did the updates.  I keep getting Unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full.  Is there a problem with the site?  Or am I doing something wrong.
Thanks,
Brent

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244443/unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-desktop-full/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2016-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-25**:
Can you install any of the other packages?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2016-09-25**:
What do you see when you type apt-get install ros<\tab>   (i.e. press the tab key)?

**Comment by [NZNobody](https://answers.ros.org/users/27466/nznobody/) on 2016-09-25**:
As SL Remy pointed out, it could be that the package is not available on your repositories for your architecture (e.g ARM vs amd64). If that is the case you may be able to find the non-complete package (ros-indigo-ros-base) and then selectively find and add what you need from packages or source.

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2016-09-26**:
I did get it to work.  I had some problems with Ubuntu.  Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-26**:
Could you perhaps describe what kind of problems you had, and how you solved them? That could help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dont know if this still actual, but you can find the package only for the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu. Is that probably your problem?

---

Originally posted by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) with karma: 436 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0